# Аналитика данных на Python по смыслу

Tags: python

Как решить следующую задачу, используя python?
Много уникальных значений (до 15.000 по разным столбцам), но по смыслу они очень схожи,
Мне нужно объединить их по смыслу. Условно говоря, «сегодня плохая погода» «погода сегодня плохая» «погода не очень» итд.
В каждом столбце одинаковые по смыслу значения, но по-разному написаны. Т.е., например, в одном столбце про погоду, во втором про одежду, в третьем про обувь итд, условно говоря
Например, вот, столбец про погоду: погода сегодня хорошая, хорошая сегодня погода, погода отличная должно родить = хорошая погода
Но при этом в этой же столбце могут попасться значения «что надевать в такую погоду», «одежда для хорошей погоды», «прогноз погоды» и из них тогда по смыслу должно быть уже второе значение
И вот таких комбинаций может быть много
Просто, например, из 1000 строк, чтобы получилось 50-10 с универсальным значением подходящим по смыслу

Comment: Используйте [Embeddings](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/what-are-embeddings?ref=blog.pragmaticengineer.com) после один из [алгоритмов кластеризации](https://scikit-learn.ru/clustering/). [Вот тут](https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=sentence-similarity&sort=trending&search=embedding) можно найти модели для Embeddings выполняющиеся локально.